# show image from mysql BLOB tojsp

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc, jpa

Hi I have problem with show image from database in jsp, I have error:

HTTP Status 400 - Required Integer parameter 'id' is not present

BLOB file saved in database correct, that's my code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "skis")
public class Skis {

    @Id
    @Column(name= "skisId")
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer skisId;

    @Column(name = "company", length = 20)
    private String company;

    @Column(name = "model", length = 20)
    private String model;

    @Column(name = "description", length = 200)
    private String description;

    @Lob
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private byte[] photo;






 @Repository
public interface SkisDAO extends JpaRepository<Skis, Integer> {

   @Query("select s from Skis s where s.skisId = :skisId")
    Skis findBySkisId(@Param("skisId") Integer skisId);

}



@Controller
@RequestMapping("/skis")
public class SkisDisplayController {



    @Autowired
    private SkisDAO skisDAO;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/skisShow", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void showSkis(@RequestParam("skisId") Integer skisId, HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request)
    throws ServletException, IOException {

        Skis skis = skisDAO.findBySkisId(skisId);
        response.setContentType("image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/png, image/gif");
        response.getOutputStream().write(skis.getPhoto());

        response.getOutputStream().close();



    }
}
```

JSP:

```
<img class="media-object img-rounded img-responsive"  src="/projectName/skis/skisShow?id=${skis.skisId}" alt="photo" >
```

Someone Can help?

Comment: Firstly try  change request param in your endpoint to _@RequestParam("id")_, or change link to _src="/projectName/skis/skisShow?skisId=${skis.skisId}"_ They should be identical.

Comment: still same error, I changed skisId for id like this @RequestParam("id"), and in src I have <img class="media-object img-rounded img-responsive"  src="/projectName/skis/skisShow?id=${skis.skisId}" alt="photo" >